# PayPal Adaptive Payments without a popup or lightbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have been using Adaptive Payments for a while but recently it has started to let me down. The lightbox feature is good, but users are hardly ever signed in to their PayPal account so a popup is required. The PayPal popup gets blocked by all web browsers these days and my users are not noticing this, even though I have a big message to warn them next to the payment button.

I have tested and have working the full page solution, i.e. redirecting to
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-XXXX

This works fine though I also need to customise the page logo on the PayPal page depending on the domain (I provide my technology white labelled).

Is there any PayPal service that allows me to perform charges on behalf of other users business accounts or do I need each business customer to create their own API account with PayPal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Permission API to do transactions on behalf of other account holders, https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/permissions/